# What is "mgt-todo" in mgt-react 2.8.0 what about other todo lists other than "Tasks"

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Where can I find all the React equivalent of the tags I see in the playground?
I am looking for . I tested with <Task but it only brings on task for myself.

In the explorer,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists/tasks/tasks
```

brings 3 tasks
Also I have tasks in other lists too. how do I get them in MGT?

Thank you

Comment: the documentation for React seems to be here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/overview (see the components tab)

Comment: There is no mention of React there but I figured out that every  mgt-? should be ? with first letter uppercase; So mgt-agenda is <Agenda /> thank you

Comment: @OferGal this is what you might have missed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react#usage. Do you think it would be more helpful to have all the component names in a section in the docs?